# running a loop while numpy array contains no zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to run a loop while there are no zeros in my numpy array. was wondering if there was a good way of checking array for zeros rather than going through it line by line.

Comment: Please show us some code, maybe? What's the shape of your array, for starters? What are you actually doing in the larger scheme of things?

Comment: Running a loop with numpy is _usually_ bad design, but you need to show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.all](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
while np.all(myarray != 0):
    dostuff
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach can be to use [np.count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```
while np.count_nonzero(arr) == arr.size:
    #your code here
```

Comment: `count_nonzero` returns an ND array if `arr` has more than one dimension, so you probably need to flatten `arr` in the call. Also, OP wants to know if there are *no* zeros, so doesn't this have to be something like `!= len(arr)`?

Comment: @mtrw I am sorry but I think you are mistaken here, count_nonzero always an integer, if the axis is not given, since the default value of the axis is None so it will return an integer even for a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Oh, I missed that the call flattens the array internally if `axis` is left at `None` - nice.

Comment: @mtrw thank you for the second suggestion I think the edit fixes the condition.